# For every new entry, copy that value to another column, but if the new entry is just a repetition in its column do not copy that

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

The scenario is of creating a PRODUCT LIST from the PURCHASE LIST. Every PURCHASE history is entered in a column, and those products are needed to be auto added in another column, but in case if a previously entered PRODUCT in PURCHASE is again entered, then it need not to be repeated in the PRODUCT LIST.

***See screenshot of the sample spreadsheet.***

[image]

In this sample sheet, Column A is the PURCHASE LIST, and Column F is what I need to extract from Column A. Every product entered in Column A is needed to be auto added in to Column F, but if a Value in Column A repeats itself multiple times, that value only need to be entered in Column F Once.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's better to post data rather than screenshots. People can more easily follow and help. In my case, I had some spare time and typed it all out again to demo the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one item from purchase list then you need to extract unique items. You can do it in various way. With `Excel365` you can use `UNIQUE()` function like

```
=UNIQUE(A4:A100)
```

If you want to sum total purchase then you can use `SUMIFS()` like-

```
=SUMIFS(B4:B14,A4:A14,F4#)
```

Remember `#` hash will only work on `Excel365` not to other versions. For older version of excel use below formula to extract unique items from purchase list and use `SUMIFS()` without hash `#`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$4:$A$100,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($F$3:F3,$A$4:$A$100),0,0),0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the [UNIQUE](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-unique-function) formula for that.

In your F4, paste this formula: `=UNIQUE(A4:A15,FALSE,TRUE)`

All cells below F4 should already be empty before you do this.

What it looks like:
[image: screenshot of solution]